# What is the assumed name of Jon Snow's mother, as told to Arya Stark?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, jon-snow

*Related to the book series A Song of Ice and Fire:*

I forgot the assumed name of Jon Snows mother that was told to Arya Stark by a lord (forgot his name - first name Edrik I think), in the third book, *A Storm of Swords*. It was told to her when she was hold captive by the brotherhood, before the hound took her.

I think the first name was Wylla or something similar, although I may have remembered the name from when his father Eddard Stark said it in the first book, *A Game of Thrones*. Please correct and remind me of the real "assumed" name of Jon Snow's mother. Full name is required.

*(keep in mind that I'm on the last written book of this series, no spoilers please)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The name is [Wylla](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wylla). The person who tells Arya is [Edric Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Edric_Dayne), the lord of Starfall and [Beric Dondarrion's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Beric_Dondarrion) squire. It is the same name that Ned gives Robert at the very beginning of AGOT.

Comment: I beg your pardon? Was there something about my answer that sounded ignorant to you? You may have failed to understand that last names were something that common people did not have. For example, Davos was just "Davos" before he was knighted, but afterwards he became Ser Davos Seaworth, and subsequently also received a lordship. Ashara Dayne was someone who was also mentioned early on as a potential mother. Wylla is assumed to be a wet nurse from Dorne.

Comment: "If you haven't read this book, please delete your post and do not provide an answer. –Secko". Wow, pretty rude. The answer is spot on. And you did say "no spoilers", how do you know that something wasn't kept from you deliberately? Have you looked at TLP's profile, hundreds of upvotes for ASOIAF answers?

Comment: @TLP Alright, hold on. I was convinced that the name told by Lord Beric to Arya contained two parts, that is why I referred to it as the last name. I still don't know what it was, it might have been Wylla the wet nurse or something, I'll grant you that. I have searched through the third book, but for all the swords in Westeros I could not find it. I posted here, hoping that someone could shed some light on this. When you provided an answer that I thought not satisfying, I may have ranted in the comment, but didn't mean to insult, please know that.

Comment: @Secko I can guarantee that if a last name had been provided for Wylla, I would be aware of it. And it would also be on the wiki.

Comment: @TLP It may be so, but I couldn't remember, hence the question. Anyway, thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 9):

Kindle version comes to the rescue (quote is from Chapter 43 (ARYA) of Storm of Swords):

> "Milk brothers. Not blood. My lady mother had no milk when I was
>   little, so Wylla had to nurse me."
>
> Arya was lost. "Who's Wylla?"
>
> "Jon Snow's mother. He never told you? She's served us for years and
>   years. Since before I was born."
>
> "Jon never knew his mother. Not even her name." Arya gave Ned a wary
>   look. "You know her? Truly?" Is he making mock of me? "If you lie I'll
>   punch your face."
>
> "Wylla was my wetnurse," he repeated solemnly. "I swear it on the
>   honor of my House."
>
> "You have a house?" That was stupid; he was a squire, of course he has
>   a House. "Who are you?"
>
> "My lady?" Ned looked embarrassed. "I'm Edric Dayne, the ... the Lord
>   of Starfall."

Comment: It is fairly weird that they called him Ned when his name was Edric.

Comment: @TLP - Yeah I did a reread recently and that part intrigued me as well :)

Comment: No weirder than Ned being a short/familiar nickname for Edward in our world though?

Comment: @Ash The weird part would be that the nickname Ned is valid for two different names: Edric and Eddard.

Comment: @TLP same here, when I was first reading it I thought that it was because the name started with the letters "Ed." I believe it would be the same in real world with names such as Edward, Edmund, Edgar, Edwin, etc.

Comment: @Eran Nicely done, I have found it. It is in chapter 43 Arya. I don't know which answer to accept right now, but TLP answered first. So plus one for you, I would appreciate it if you added the number of the chapter. Thanks you. For the life of me, I cannot say why I remembered that Wylla had a different name. :S

Comment: It's as weird as Peggy being short for Margaret!

Comment: nice explanation here on why Ned is short for names beginning with Ed: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/why-is-lord-eddard-nicknamed-ned

Answer (score -3):

Commoners **do not** have last names. Wylla is just Wylla. Additionally, if you reread the very first book in the series, chapter 39, you will find pretty easily who Jon Snow's real mother and father are (hint: Ice and Fire).

Comment: This seems more like a comment to the accepted answer, as you have provided no new information or support for yours.